# Программа для MySQL, ZendStudio

Tags: mysql

Какую программу для работы с MySQL посоветуете? Чтоб для администрирования Баз данных как на уделенке так и на локале. Создание таблиц и тд весь функционал. Желательно чтоб бесплатная была. Сейчас пользуюсь SQL Manager Lite for MySQL. Но может что и получше есть?

---

И Еще вопрос. Как заставить работать ZendStudio 5.5.0 на Виндосе 7?

Comment: А чем вас ваша не устраивает? Что вы подразумеваете под словом "получше"?
Я думаю функционала у SQL Manager Lite for MySQL для администрирования вполне хватает.

Comment: Ну мало ли. Просто допустим моя прога платная, а если использовать бесполатно то некоторые функции отрубаются

Comment: Это задается в программе. На функциональность самого приложения MySQL никак не влияет.

Answer (score 2):

Из платных, я бы посоветовал [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php). По функционалу ничем не уступает EMS SQL Manager. И, в отличии от последнего, так же замечательно работает и в Linux под wine (хотя, как я понимаю, это вам не нужно)

Из бесплатных, есть очень неплохая IDE [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). Но она по функционалу несколько уступает предыдущим двум.

По второму вопросу. Первая-же ссылка из google: [Zend Studio 5.5 и Windows 7](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/73522/)

Comment: Спасибо действительно неплохая прога